# Manipulating service data in component in Angular

Tags: angular, service, angular5, data-sharing

In my angular application, I have stored categories in a service.
In my component I'm removing the first categories from the array and displaying it. The first category is "ALL", and I don't want to display that.

So when I edit the `createCategories` array in component, the service data also gets changed. How can I keep the original data in service and just manipulate the data in the component?

Below is the code in the component:

```
this.createCategories = this.myServ.getCategories();
this.createCategories.splice(0, 1);
```

The service `getCategories` method:

```
public getCategories() {
   return this.categories;
}
```

Now what is happening is every time we call the component one category is removed from the array and also in the service.

Please guide.

Comment: use this approach for copy your result object and then edit: duplicateObject = <YourObjType> JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(originalObject));

Comment: @Hasan and if the categories are objects with internal functions, your solution throws an error. Not the best one at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, for instance, use an array function. Let's try with filter :

```
public getCategories() {
  return this.myServ.getCategories()
    .filter((el, index, array) => index !== 0);
}
```

This will return a new array, without the first element.

Comment: @shruti: `index !== 0` is the conditional statement that is assuming that the "ALL" item is _always_ the first item in the array, and is always there. You might want to be a little more defensive with your coding to prevent bugs creeping in later (i.e. search for "All" instead, or check the ordinal position and the value etc).

Comment: Agreed, but he asked to remove the first item of the array.

Comment: Yup, but also that he didn't want to display "ALL" :-)

Comment: Thanks @trichetriche .I'm inserting ALL at the first position in the categories array.This works for me.